# Check if parsed json is NSNULL

Tags: json, swift, nsnull

I am parsing a JSON response and trying to check if one of my keys is null. How would I go about this? I have the following:

```
var routingNumber = (dic.value(forKey: "result") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "routingNumber") as! String
```

and this returns:

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x107d238c8) to 'NSString' (0x107329c40).

How would I check if the value is NSNULL?

```
if( something != NSNULL){
    do something
}else{
    do something else
}
```

Comment: if let routingNumber = (dic["result"] as? [String: Any])?["routingNumber"] as? String { }

Comment: Do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use a Swift dictionary. Do not use `value(forKey:)` to get a value unless you have a specific reason to be using KVC (which you don't have in this case).

Comment: Wy not use the Swift dictionary?

Answer (score 11):

You can extract value from dic like this.

```
if let value = (dict["key"] as? String) 
{ 
  //NOT NULL
} 
else 
{
   //NULL
}
```

Comment: The parentheses are not needed.

Comment: Does this make sure that the value for `dict["key"]` isn't nil AND also a `String` (not other types)?

Answer (score 6):

create below function

```
func isNsnullOrNil(object : AnyObject?) -> Bool
{
    if (object is NSNull) || (object == nil)
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}
```

call function where you want to check for null or nil value

```
if isNsnullOrNil((dic.value(forKey: "result") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "routingNumber"))
{
    print("object is null or nil")
}
else
{
    print("object is not  null or nil")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem once.

**CHECK FOR IF NSNULL**

```
if let result = dic["result"] as? NSDictionary {
    // There is a dictionary

    if let routingNumber = result["routingNumber"] as? String {
         // There is a routingNumber
    }
    else if let routingNumber = result["routingNumber"] as? NSNull {
         // There is routingNumber but Null
    }
    else {
        // No routingNumber
    }
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Why use `NSDictionary`? Use a Swift dictionary.

Comment: user2423476's question used `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let result = dict["result"] as? [String:Any], let routingNumber = result["routingNumber"] as? String { 
    print("the routingNumber is \(routingNumber)")
} else { 
    print("nil") 
}
```